# PHP file doesn't run

Tags: php, html

I have this two files: 

`index.html`

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And `welcome.php`

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome, <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is example from [there](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

When the user fills the form and hits "enter" it should display:

```
Welcome, the_name_you_enter
Your email address is address_you_enter
```

But for me it only displays `welcome.php` source code (I am using Safari 7).
Does anyone knows why?

Comment: what web server are you running? xampp? wamp?

Comment: Are you running this in an environment where PHP is available to you?

Comment: Nothing to do with the browser but it sounds like your web server is not running - are you running this on localhost? This is not really a programming question - it's more of an environmental one.

Comment: The files are on my computer - its why it doesn't run?

Comment: @nicael Yes - to run PHP you need a web server with the PHP executeable. XAMPP/WAMP on windows work fine if you want to run it on localhost. MAMP is good for OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because the PHP file is not executed on a web server or PHP is not enabled on your webserver.

You are probably trying to access the file directly using file://

Take a look at [MAMP](http://mamp.info) (I am assuming you are using OS X)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your calling up the page from a server that is not executing php.